# What is the meaning of the XML nodes and attributes in the MILA data format for text tagging in NLP?

Tags: nlp

The beginning of one of MILAs XML records from the [knesset Hebrew tagging](https://github.com/NLPH/knesset-2004-2005) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<corpus comment="versions info: lexicon :16/06/2009; morphologicalAnalyzer:1.6 (16/06/2009); corpus schema 16/06/2009; lexicon schema 16/06/2009" email="mila@cs.technion.ac.il" maintainer="Dalia Bojan" name="Analysis Results">
  <article id="1">
    <paragraph id="1">
      <sentence id="1">
        <token id="1" surface="תוכן">
          <analysis id="1" score="0.0">
            <base dottedLexiconItem="תֻּכַּן" lexiconItem="תוכן" lexiconPointer="15162" transliteratedLexiconItem="twkn">
              <verb binyan="Pu'al" gender="masculine" number="singular" person="3" register="formal" root="tkn" spelling="standard" tense="past"/>
            </base>
          </analysis>
          <analysis id="2" score="0.0">
            <base dottedLexiconItem="הוּכַן" lexiconItem="הוכן" lexiconPointer="17372" transliteratedLexiconItem="hwkn">
              <verb binyan="Huf'al" gender="masculine" number="singular" person="2" register="formal" root="kwn" spelling="standard" tense="future"/>
            </base>
          </analysis>
          <analysis id="3" score="0.0">
            <base dottedLexiconItem="הוּכַן" lexiconItem="הוכן" lexiconPointer="17372" transliteratedLexiconItem="hwkn">
              <verb binyan="Huf'al" gender="feminine" number="singular" person="3" register="formal" root="kwn" spelling="standard" tense="future"/>
            </base>
          </analysis>
          <analysis id="4" score="1.0">
            <base dottedLexiconItem="תֹכֶן" lexiconItem="תוכן" lexiconPointer="20055" transliteratedLexiconItem="twkn">
              <noun gender="masculine" number="singular" register="formal" spelling="standard" status="construct"/>
            </base>
```

What goes into everything from `<analysis>` down?

1. Why are there multiple analyses?
2. What do all the attributes on `base` mean?
3. What is an "analysis" even? How does it work?

The MILA website has been down for some time so there is no documentation on the web as far as I can tell. Would like to understand their data format for tagging texts.